# Windows 7: 'drive cleanup' actually cost 1gb of space. How can I fix that?

Tags: windows-7, disk-cleanup

I just ran the 'drive cleanup' utility on Windows 7 after it complained that my C drive had only 2 gb free (of 40 gb).  I ran it, and now I'm down to 900mb free, after it said it would remove some 4gb of error logs.

What happened?  Where can I look for the space hogging error files and the like, and delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm my personal experience... Don't use Microsoft products that "help".  They really don't, and if they do, their minimal.  If you're looking to clear/clean up your drive, then I suggest using [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner), IOBit's [Advanced System Care Free](http://www.iobit.com/advancedwindowscareper.html) (*warning* Advanced System care by default turns off the option to record any Blue Screen errors, you have to [stop it](http://forums.iobit.com/showthread.php?t=6630) from doing so), and also deleting any files that you don't need to have.  If you're using the C: drive as a dedicated OS drive and have a second drive to store other files, make sure that your documents drive point to the second drive.

If you are using the hibernation options within Windows, then deleting the hiberfil.sys associated with that will also help.  This is where the "Windows Cleanup" should be useful, however a [manual](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-delete-hibernation-file-hiberfil-sys/) deletion and disabling may be necessary.

I would also suggest using a Defragger like Piriform's [Defraggler](http://www.piriform.com/defraggler) as well, as that may help things out as well.  (*Note: Windows 7 automatically takes care of defragmentation, but I feel that it doesn't do a good enough job*)

Finally, 40 Gigs just doesn't cut it any more.  Even for a dedicated Windows OS, that's cutting it close.  Once Service packs, and more updates come along it will be cutting things really close.  I would suggest looking into purchasing a larger drive.  It'll save you in the long run.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into those.  CCleaner didn't do much to help (90mb found and cleaned).  I have some six drives at the moment, and only 20 gb is listed for the system, documents, and program files.  There's some other space hog that's not listed...

Comment: hiberfil.sys-- a big ol' 9gb of space.  Guess that's what I get for 12 gb of RAM and never hibernating...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do to try to get space back:

1. Turn off system restore.  This introduces a risk that you cannot roll back Windows if something goes wrong, but it will net you some space
2. Try a different cleanup utility, such as CCleaner.  It may find things that Windows' Drive Cleanup misses.
3. Try a utility such as  [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) which will visualize your disk space usage.

Hope this helps.  Of course, buying a bigger drive (80GB are dirt cheap these days) would definitely help.

Comment: I find 500GB drives 10% more expensive than 80GB drives.

Comment: Well, regardless, drives are dirt cheap anymore, which was the point I was trying to get across :)  Heck, 1TBs can be found for under 100 if you shop around.

Comment: Yeah, the drive is actually a partition, not the entire drive.  Not sure if that matters for the point of the question, though.

Comment: WinDirStat is a great utility, thanks for pointing it out.